# Robotframework - how to open Google Playstore app

Tags: android, automation, appium, robotframework

I want to test download my application from Playstore by using Robotframework.

First, I've checked the package and activity of Playstore.

```
C:\Users\DMKT\AppData\Local> adb shell dumpsys window | findstr "mCurrentFocus"
  mCurrentFocus=Window{e9011c u0 com.android.vending/com.android.vending.AssetBrowserActivity}
```

Then I tried to run testcase. The testcase is PASS but no application is opened at Android device.

```
** Settings ***
Library         AppiumLibrary

*** Variables ***
${REMOTE_URL}     http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub
${PLATFORM_NAME}    Android
${DEVICENAME}   Galaxy S9
${APP_PACKAGE}      com.android.vending
${APP_ACTIVITY}     com.android.vending.AssetBrowserActivity

*** Test Cases ***
Test
    Open Application    ${REMOTE_URL}    platformName=${PLATFORM_NAME}    deviceName=${DEVICENAME} appPackage=${APP_PACKAGE}       appActivity=${APP_ACTIVITY}
```

Anything is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your variabel ${DEVICENAME} change with id Device Name, you can search id device name with command `$ adb devices` in terminal

Comment: After change device name with id, still no application is opened. :(

Comment: enabling all debug options on android:
- USB debugging
- Install via USB
- USB Debugging (Security Settings)

Comment: Actually, only Google Playstore that's can't be opened. I've tried to open other app such as chrome app, then it's opened.